# Installing the console application as a Windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation, topshelf

I'm writing a simple Windows Service based on [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com). How to install my application as a service? I tried to execute `SpyService.exe install`, but it doesn't work.

What is the difference between next two ways of configuring the service?

```
var cfg = RunnerConfigurator.New(
    x =>
    {
        x.ConfigureService<SpyService>(s =>
        {
            s.Named("SpyService");
            s.HowToBuildService(name => new SpyService());
            s.WhenStarted(tc => { 
                XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(".\\log4net.config")); 
                tc.Start(); });
            s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
        });
        x.RunAsFromInteractive();

        x.SetDescription("Сервис логирования действий пользователя.");
        x.SetDisplayName("SpyService");
        x.SetServiceName("SpyService");
    });

Runner.Host(cfg, args);
```

and

```
var host = HostFactory.New(x =>
{                
    x.Service<SpyService>(s =>
    {
        s.SetServiceName("SpyService");
        s.ConstructUsing(name => new SpyService());
        s.WhenStarted(service =>
        {
            XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(".\\log4net.config"));
            service.Start();
        });
        s.WhenStopped(service => service.Stop());
    });

    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
    x.SetDescription("Сервис логирования действий пользователя.");
    x.SetDisplayName("SpyService");
    x.SetServiceName("SpyService");
});

host.Run();
```

I noticed that if I use the second method the service is successfully installed, but there is not possible to start the service with `x.RunAsFromInteractive()` as in first way.

Comment: did you run that command elevated?

Comment: hey dude! pardon me for asking you this way, but I see no other way to communicate. please undelete your answer in that mysql dates question! nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Topshelf are you using? The old syntax was `SpyService.exe service install` but has been simplified.

Comment: Per your question on the first vs. second way, only the first way accepts any command line arguments from the console app entry point. The second method likely shouldn't really be supported.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is obsoleted in the latest version (2.2), afaik.

Regarding RunAsFromInteractive(), looking at the topshelf source code, I see that it called RunAs() with empty username/password:

```
public void RunAsFromInteractive()
{
    this.RunAs("", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Console Command as Administrator first, then run the install command